# how to hide the border of text area in ui-tinymce

Tags: angularjs, tinymce, rich-text-editor

I want to do inline editing in ui-tinymce. Its the text area and I want to hide its border. It should edit only when user clicks on text area. I am inline as true, but still it shows border.

```
$scope.tinymceOptions = {
        inline: true,
        menubar: false,
        toolbar: "bold italic underline styleselect",
        statusbar: false,
        skin: 'lightgray',
        theme : 'modern'
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your tinymceOptions :

```
inline_boundaries: false
```

If still doesn't work you can always override the border from your css by :

```
.mce-container {
   border: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using inline mode, I had a persistent border that was visible when the editable area is active, I solved it by adding the following to my inline styles:

```
:focus-visible {
   outline:0;
}
```

you can probably make it not add outline in a more "proper" way, but I find it hard to edit in the theme css files due to their messy nature.